# Problems with Self-Signed Certificate in webservice hosted in ISS - KEY_USAGE_BIT_INCORRECT

Tags: iis, openssl, ssl-certificate

I installed a webservice in IIS, and i need to configurate SSL to clients works.

But the clients show error: "Failure in SSL library, ususally a protocol error. Error:1000012e:SSL routines: OPENSSL_internal: KEY_USAGE_BIT_INCORRECT"

The client app was developer by another company and they doesn't know the answer to this error.

I read about this error in another platforms and apparently these are problems with self-signed certificates.

So,i read about free CA to create certificate, but for example "Lets Encrypt". It needs the website to be configured with a hostname to be able to generate the certificate. But i use the webservice only in intranet, so i need access via IP.

Any ideas how to use this service to create a certificate to intranet without use the default Windows way?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Certificate management is usually the responsibility of your network/domain administrators, so instead of reading you can seek guidance from them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a self-signed certificate and encounter a "KEY_USAGE_BIT_INCORRECT" error, it is important to ensure that the certificate is configured correctly. This error usually occurs when the SSL certificate does not match the key usage specified in the certificate.

You need to generate a new certificate to include the Digital Signature value, or remove the entire Key Usage extension. This link explains [how to create a self-signed certificate using SAN and extensions](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-Create-Self-Signed-Certificate-With-Extensions-and-Sans-Using-Openssl).